# Use of uninitialized value $end_time1 in string eq .......error in perl

Tags: database, perl, null

i want to retrive some data from my database,if $end_time1 is null then will be update table ,otherwise will do nothing ,but when i run the code,i found the $end_time1 is null,then will be update the table  ,but if not null ,it's will be return the error :

```
Use of uninitialized value $end_time1 in string eq ........
```

part of my code :

```
my $select_sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id ,H1, H2, addr1, addr2, time_1, time_2,   
end_time_1,end_time_2,count1,count2 FROM service") or die "$dbh->errstr";
$select_sth->execute() or die "$dbh->errstr";
while (my @row_ref = $select_sth->fetchrow_array)
 {
    my $Rid = $row_ref[0];
    my $addr1 = $row_ref[3];
    my $addr2 = $row_ref[4];
    my $end_time1 = "NULL" unless $row_ref[7];
    my $end_time2 = "NULL" unless $row_ref[8];
    my $count1 = $row_ref[9];
    my $count2 = $row_ref[10];
    if($end_time1 eq "NULL")
     {
        print "$end_time1 is null\n";
        $dbh->do ("update service set end_time_1 = '$datetime_now' where id = $Rid");
     }
 }
```

please someone what's wrong with my code ?how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only sets `$endtime1` if `$row_ref[7]` is not defined. This means that `$endtime1` is undefined if `$row_ref[7]` does have a value, so you get that `Use of uninitialized value $end_time1 in string eq...` error when you test it.

Change your code so that `$endtime1` will either be set to `$row_ref[7]` (if it is defined) or to `NULL`:

```
    my $end_time1 = $row_ref[7] || 'NULL';
```

Then you can use your existing code:

```
if ($end_time1 eq "NULL")
{
    print "end_time1 is null\n";
    $dbh->do ("update service set end_time_1 = '$datetime_now' where id = $Rid");
}
```

The same issue exists for `$endtime2`, so you may want to make a similar alteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html):

```
if ( !defined $end_time1 ) {
    print "end_time1 is null\n";
}
```

Comment: i want to print when end_time1 is null  , but your code will be print every time Whether end_time1 is null